# Nginx dynamic proxy redirection

Tags: proxy, nginx

I was hoping to achieve something like this:

```
location = / {
    if ($args ~ "^url=(.+)") { #gets the "url" get parameter
        set $key1 $1;
        proxy_pass $key1; #use the parameter as proxy address
    }
}
```

Is this even possible ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
location / {
    proxy_pass http://backend$arg_url;
}
```

- http://nginx.org/r/proxy_pass
- http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#variables
- http://wiki.nginx.org/IfIsEvil

Comment: Hi VBart, in my case i don't have a static part in my URL, i just want to proxy to whatever URL was passed to the / location as a get argument. For instance : /?url=www.stackoverflow.com.

Comment: So, what's the problem with `proxy_pass http://$arg_url;`? Did you read the link to the documentation above? Please, look at the end of the `proxy_pass` reference.

Comment: I even quote it here: _A server name, its port and passed URI can also be specified using variables_.

Comment: Yes, that s useful read, thanks. Also do you know if there is way in case of redirected page to have relative URL be still following to the original server ?

Comment: http://nginx.org/r/proxy_redirect and http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_sub_module.html
Usually I take $5 for each link to the official documentation, and $100 for every quote from it.

Comment: oh well i'll have deep look at that before i ask further, and many thanks for the help so far

Comment: Some 3rd party modules can also be useful for your task, like: http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpSubsModule and http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpLuaModule

Comment: I keep on getting a 502 when using the location block from your answer. My url looks like domain.com/proxy?url=www.site.com, and my location block: location /proxy { proxy_pass http://arg_url; }. Any ideas ?

Comment: Nvm i got it form there : http://www.nginx-discovery.com/2011/05/day-51-proxypass-and-resolver.html, needed to add a resolver for the DNS as the domain i resolved on the fly. Still fighting to have the URI rewritten though ..